# UITabBar alignment issue in Portrait & Landscape mode in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uitabbar, landscape-portrait

I have created a custom TabBar which operates in both portrait & landscape mode .In portrait mode ,images and text are centrally aligned , while in landscape mode text is not centrally aligned.

**Portrait View**

[image]

**Landscape View**

[image]

**My query is how can I get centrally aligned icon and text in landscape mode?
How can I get alignment same as in portrait mode.**

Comment: did you resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use autoLayout constraint while designing your app in order work for both modes, you can do something like this :

```
YourText.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: YourImage.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```